# print request body in the console in Yii 2

Tags: yii2

in Yii2 rest API, I need to print the request body in the Visual Studio code's terminal. Is there a way to do that?
I tried varduming and echoing but couldn't achieve the result.

Comment: If I understand, you are trying to dump the request in the API. There are only two options in my experience: return the data to the calling function and print it out there (return jason_encode(//data here) or put the API url directly into the browser and render it as though it is a page. You can then echo within the controller.

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific about your problem. Is your problem with your rest API itself or with the API consumer (test API in web browser/postman)? What are you var_dumping/echoing? What's the actual result you are getting and what were you expecting instead?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 you can create debug message using

```
\Yii::trace("this is my debug message");
```

which is added to ./runtime/log/application.log

On the command line (e.g. in Visual Code) to see this debug messages, do this:

```
$ cd runtime/log
$ tail -f application.log
```

You can stop the `tail`-command using ^C.

If this is too much output, you can refine debugging messag output in `./config/web.php`:

```
$config = [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'log' => [
            ...
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'trace'],
                'logVars' => [],  // no $SERVER vars
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
return $config;
```